# Store and retrieve objects from redis?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have several Mountain objects which have id and name.

I stored these objects like that

```
HMSET Mountain:1 id "1" name "Mo1"
HMSET Mountain:2 id "2" name "Mo2"
HMSET Mountain:3 id "3" name "Mo2"
```

How can I get all Mountain Objects? Or are there any better way storing objects in redis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it with 2 command :

```
KEYS Mountain:*
HGETALL <everykeys>
```

But , if you can, it's better to not use KEYS command , so you can do something like this :

```
HMSET Mountain:1 id "1" name "Mo1"
SADD Montains Mountain:1
HMSET Mountain:2 id "2" name "Mo2"
SADD Montains Mountain:2
HMSET Mountain:3 id "3" name "Mo3"
SADD Montains Mountain:3
```

and get it :

```
SMEMBERS Mountain
HGETALL <everykeys>
```

Redis is a key/value system with extra data type, so you have to build your index
So for having a name indexing for example, if name are unique:

```
HSET Mountains:IdByName "Mo3" 3
```

and you will get the id :

```
HGET Mountains:IdByName "Mo3"
```

for non unique lets use set again

```
SADD Mountains:IdByName:Mo3 3
```

And you will increase the number of keys and that why KEYS is not recommend , because to expensive

next step is use a lua script for having/setting  hash from/and index

Comment: Ok. I understand concept. Are there any way get Mountain which name is "Mo2"?

Comment: redis have some more complex data type then classic key/value but not enought for thid. you have to create you own . i put it in answer , that quite usefull